# empty site after using nmp run build (vue 2 cli)

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Im using project vue 2 cli + vuex + router (without history mode) but when Im opening index.html, after "nmp run build" command, site is empty. How can I solve it... I need site to be opened on index.html (like common cdn project)

Comment: Please provide **more** debugging info that just this. [ask]

Comment: do you serve the bundle on a server? or do you just try to make it run like opening a index.html in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

> The dist directory is meant to be served by an HTTP server (unless you've configured publicPath to be a relative value), **so it will not work if you open dist/index.html directly over file:// protocol**.

[Source](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#previewing-locally)

#### One way to test your build, is to install Serve:

```js
// install Serve globally
npm install -g serve
// Run in project root, with folder name as input
serve -s dist
```